# security updates for SP 2013 farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security, update, patching

I am trying to update security updates for SP 2013. I tried to download one security update it has almost 52 items.How can I install these all items in one shot or quickly.Please suggest quickly.

Comment: Where are you downloading them from? Are you downloading SU for each month? Should be enough with the latest months as most of the patches in SharePoint are cumulative.

Comment: We have downloaded and installed update from below URL : https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4011653

Comment: Post installation of [KB4011653 ] update, server is not up how ever it's pining

Comment: one more thing, post installation of security updates, do we need to run configuration wizard?

Answer (score 1):

You can get standalone package from this url: [Download the security update KB4011653 for the 64-bit version of SharePoint Foundation 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6f0015d6-c52a-4feb-8c24-96a0667214b7)

After applying the patch, you have to run the SharePoint config wizard on all the SharePoint  servers in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download KB4011653 for SharePoint foundation 2013 from : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011653/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforsharepointfoundation2013january9-2018

If you have multiple servers in this farm , you need to install the patches on all servers and run configuration wizard on each servers .